# how to get specific attribute value from stdout json in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts, ansible-template, json-query

**instance_tags.stdout** output would look like

[image]

Expected output of fallowing snippet is **App Server-Development**

```
- name: get instance tags
  win_shell: aws ec2 --region us-east-1 describe-tags \ --filters "Name=resource-id,Values={{instance_id}}"
  register: instance_tags


- name: echo instance tags
  debug:
    msg: "{{instance_tags.stdout | json_query('Tags[?Key==''AMSPatchGroup''].Value')}}"
```

**But Actual Output is**

[image]

Comment: Can you share output of the following debug: msg: "{{instance_tags.stdout.Tags[0] }}"

Comment: Please don't post code snippets as images; it is explicitly mentioned in the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You at least want `instance_tags.stdout | from_json | ...` since `.stdout` is a string, not an actual structure

One can see this behavior with a simple experiment showing `{{ '{"a":"b"}' | json_query("a") }}` returns `""` just like your experience, but `{{ '{"a":"b"}' | from_json | json_query("a") }}` produces `"b"` as one would expect